# Matrix Calculus and Linear Transformations

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, linear-transformations

I'm working on making the jump from differentiating real valued functions ($f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) and vector valued functions ($g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$) to matrix valued functions ($h: \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$) but am having trouble with matrix valued functions.

I see that for first two cases, the total derivative $\mathscr{D}f$ is a linear transformation that can be represented as the Jacobian matrix, but when I was going through the [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), I was confused on page ten.  The authors show

$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{a}^{T} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{b}}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{a b}^T$$

and I interpreted this as computing the total derivative $\mathscr{D}f$ (the total derivative is the concept I'm trying to understand) where $f: \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ takes $X$ to $\mathbf{a}^{T} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{b}$.

1. Is this the right interpretation of the authors' notation, or are they (by using the partial notation here) computing something fundamentally different that I'm just missing?
2. Since I interpreted this as the total derivative, I tried working with the Frechet definition to compute the term $\mathscr{D}f(X)H$, but since $f$ takes $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, I'm having trouble lining up dimensions as $f(X + H)$ and $f(X)$ are $\mathbb{R}$ but $\mathscr{D}f(X)H$ is $\mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$. This makes me think I'm mixing up concepts...  Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: May I suggest looking up "Tensor Notation" on YouTube where you will find a series of my videos. In my opinion, your good question is not worth figuring out in this notation. The matrix notation is unsuited for this category of problems and is therefore confusing. Insistence on this notation does the field of applied mathematics a great disservice. This is an example of "orgies of formalism" that Hermann Weyl argued so eloquently against.

Look, you are differentiating linear functions and finding it difficult. It's not your fault - it's the book you're reading.